# Add audio file to iPod?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

I have a recent iPod touch (just over 1 year old). 
I have an audio file from a voice recorder I'd like to load to it. The audio is 2-1/2 hours, a voice recording, but when copied to iTunes, it shows as a song. And when the iPod is attached, via cable to the computer, there's no option to just choose individual songs. The file is too long to load to cloud. Similarly produced files were only 1-1/2 hours max, and went thru cloud just fine.

Any suggestion how to move the file to iPod?

Edit - Update - As I noted in the comment below, the 1:20 file transferred just fine. Today, I tried a file that was 1:30 (90 minutes) and it won't show as available to transfer. The simple ongoing solution, is to just break into multiple files, 80 minutes maximum. Which coincidently, lets me burn to CD if I wish.

Comment: What do you mean by 'no option to choose individual songs' ? can't you sync your iTunes Library to the iPod ?

Comment: For whatever reason, the large audio file would not sync. I broke it into two files, each about 1:20 and it's all set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iTunes, click on your device. Scroll down a little and click Manually Manage Songs. Then go to music (on the side) and add your song.

If you have the iTunes sidebar enabled, you should be able to drag your song on top of your iPod, and it should sync.